# Как сдеать после перезагрузки страницы выбранный вариант "option" становился "selected"?

Tags: php, get

```
<form action="" method="get">
<select name="sl" id="sl">
  <option value="1">Text 1</option>
  <option value="2">Text 2</option>
  <option select="selected" value="3">Text 3</option>
  <option value="4">Text 4</option>
  <option value="5">Text 5</option>
  <option value="6">Text 6</option>
  <option value="7">Text 7</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>

<?php
  if(isset($_GET['sl']))
    selected option - select="selected" 
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я Вас верно понял, то попробуйте думать в эту сторону:

```
<?
if(!empty($_GET['sl'])){
$selected = $_GET['sl'];
}
?>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
var optionValue = <?=$selected?>;
$("#sl").val(optionValue)
.find("option[value=" + optionValue +"]").attr('selected', true);
});
</script>

<form action="" method="get">
<select name="sl" id="sl">
  <option value="1">Text 1</option>
  <option value="2">Text 2</option>
  <option select="selected" value="3">Text 3</option>
  <option value="4">Text 4</option>
  <option value="5">Text 5</option>
  <option value="6">Text 6</option>
  <option value="7">Text 7</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Демо-пример *(скопируйте код и запустите на локалке)*

```
<?php $sl = !empty($_GET['sl']) ? (int)$_GET['sl'] : 0; ?>

<form action="" method="get">
    <select name="sl">
        <?php for ($i = 0; $i++ < 7;) { ?>
            <?php if ($sl == $i) { ?>
                <?php $selected = 'selected' ?>
                <option <?=$selected?> value="<?=$i?>">Text <?=$i?></option>
            <?php } else { ?>
                <?php $selected = '' ?>
                <option <?=$selected?> value="<?=$i?>">Text <?=$i?></option>
            <?php } ?>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```